# Entry Cursor Position is not consistent or rather different in Android and UWP in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having an `Entry` in my Xamarin Forms app. I want to check if the Cursor is positioned at the end of the entry i.e., the cursor should be positioned at the end of the text in `Entry`. I am checking this through `if (entryField.CursorPosition == e.NewTextValue.Length)` in **UWP** it works but in **Android** CursorPosition is always less than the corresponding CursorPosition value in UWP. If in UWP `CursorPosition = 5` then in Android it will be `CursorPosition = 4`. Hence, I cannot check if CursorPosition is at the end of the text. CursorPosition in Android is not equal to CursorPosition in UWP.

Here is my code in C#

```cs
private void EntryChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (entryField.CursorPosition == e.NewTextValue.Length)
    {
        //Do stuff if CursorPosition is at the end of the text
    }            
}
```

Here is me **XAML** code

```xml
<Entry x:Name="entryField" TextChanged="EntryChanged" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different criteria based on the platform your app is running:

```
int offset;

switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.Android:
      offset = e.NewTextValue.Length - 1;
      break;
    default:
      offset = e.NewTextValue.Length;
}

if (entryField.CursorPosition == offset)
{
    //Do stuff if CursorPosition is at the end of the text
}
```